# What do each choices mean at the beginning of Kingdom Hearts 3?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-3

During the tutorial section of Kingdom Hearts 3, I was given two series of choices to select from.

The first section, I was given the option to choose: **Balance**, **Vitality**, or **Wisdom**

The second section, I was given the option to choose: **Mystic**, **Warrior**, or **Guardian**.

What do these choices mean, and what should I consider when selecting them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The choices you are given determines your starting stats and ability progression respectively.

**First Option**

- Balance: 15 Attack, 8 Magic, 15 Absorbs, 105 HP, 110 MP, and 28 AP
- Vitality: 15 Attack, 8 Magic, 15 Absorbs, 120 HP, 100 MP, and 28 AP
- Wisdom: 15 Attack, 8 Magic, 15 Absorbs, 90 HP, 120 MP, and 28 AP

**Second Option**

- Mystic: You gain magic related abilities sooner than other abilities
- Warrior: You gain attack related abilities sooner than other abilities
- Guardian: You gain defense related abilities sooner than other abilities

[Source](https://samurai-gamers.com/kingdom-hearts-3/beginning-choices-ability-progression/)